# Permalink Working Only in Default expect the custom postname

Tags: mod-rewrite, centos, debian

I am having a problem with the permalink. It worked fine while was in the development phase, now that I have migrated the server to another which is Debian 6.0/Squeeze default kernel, CentOS 6 default kernel. It only works with the default permalink but doest with the custom post name permalink.

I have tried the activating the default permalink and then the post name permalink.The `.htaccess` are well located properly. I tried to check the `mod_rewrite` is enabled but couldn't find that.Tried to check in the `/etc/apache2` but there isnt a folder `apache2` file.

Please help

Comment: If there is no `mod_rewrite` it won't work. This is not a WordPress issue but a server question.

Comment: Where can I find the modwrite in the debian centOs.i am unable to locate it

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: a2enmod: command not found